# Drag and drop desde TreeView hacia Textbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy pegando un elemento de un `Treeview` hacia un `Textbox`, pero quisiera pegar el elemento en la posición que indique con el mouse como también mostrar la barra que indica donde ira el elemento a pegar, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen o al igual que se hace en el creador de expresiones del integration services

[image: Ejemplo]

[image: SSIS - Expresiones]

Acá esta mi Código

```
private void tvOperador_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    var node = (TreeNode)e.Item;
    if (node.Level > 0)
    {
        DoDragDrop(node.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}

private void txtExpresion_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string))) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void txtExpresion_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
    {
        string Item = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
        string[] split = Item.Split(':');

        txtExpresion.Text += split[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede usar el ***caret*** de `txtExpresion`:

```
private void txtExpresion_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        this.txtExpresion.Focus();       
    }            
}

private void txtExpresion_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
    {
        string Item = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
        string[] split = Item.Split(':');

        string texto = this.txtExpresion.Text.Trim();    
        int i = this.txtExpresion.GetCharIndexFromPosition(this.txtExpresion.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));

        // El espacio agregado al final es para obtener, en la fórmula de arriba, la longitud de txtExpresion.Text (Length), cuando se intente anexar al final.            
        // En caso contrario se obtendría Length - 1, lo que dejaría escapar la última letra.
        // La función GetCharIndexFromPosition() devuelve un valor cuyo rango es [0..Length - 1].
        this.txtExpresion.Text = texto.Substring(0, i) + split[1] + texto.Substring(i) + " ";
        this.txtExpresion.SelectionStart = i + split[1].Length;
    }
}

private void txtExpresion_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{            
    int i = this.txtExpresion.GetCharIndexFromPosition(this.txtExpresion.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
    this.txtExpresion.SelectionStart = i;
}
```